# Learning haskell: a recursive function for creating skip-bigrams

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm working my way through the [NLPWP Book](http://nlpwp.org/book/), and I'm at the chapter that deals with recursive functions. A recursive function for computing bigrams looks like this:

```
bigram :: [a] -> [[a]]
bigram [] = [] 
bigram [_] = []
bigram xs = take 2 xs : bigram (tail xs)
```

And if I run it on the `wordlist = ["colorless", "green", "ideas", "sleep", "furiously"]` I get this:

```
bigram chomsky

[("colorless","green"),("green","ideas"),("ideas","sleep"),("sleep","furiously")]
```

The exercise says:

> A skip-bigram is any pair of words in sentence order. Write a function skipBigrams that extracts skip-bigrams from a sentence as a list of binary tuples, using explicit recursion. Running your function on `["Colorless", "green", "ideas", "sleep", "furiously"]` should give the following output:
>
> `Prelude> skipBigrams ["Colorless", "green", "ideas", "sleep", "furiously"]`
> `[("Colorless","green"),("Colorless","ideas"),("Colorless","sleep"),("Colorless","furiously"),("green","ideas"),("green","sleep"),("green","furiously"),("ideas","sleep"),("ideas","furiously"),("sleep","furiously")]`

Here is the definition I've tried:

```
skipBigram [] = [] 
skipBigram [_] = []
skipBigram (x:xs) = [(x, (head xs)), (x, skipBigram xs)]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [(t, t)]
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [t] (bound at :3:15)
  x :: t (bound at :3:13)
  skipBigram :: [t] -> [(t, t)] (bound at :1:1)
In the expression: interactive:IHaskell384.skipBigram xs
In the expression: (x, interactive:IHaskell384.skipBigram xs)
```

Which, new to Haskell as I am, I don't understand in the slightest. What is an infinite type? A relevant binding?

*How should I define* `skipBigram` *to resolve this compile-time error?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Try this definition:**](http://ideone.com/ywn1S8)

```
skipBigram :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
skipBigram     [] = [] -- nothing to do with an empty list
skipBigram (x:xs) = [(x,y) | y <- xs] ++ skipBigram xs
```

Your `skipBigram` function is generating all the "2-tuple left-to-right combinations" of words in the list. We can capture this concept with a [simple list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) in the recursive definition. By recursively concatenating the simple list comprehensions, we gain the desired result list.

Comment: @Jono See the reference to list comprehensions

Comment: You could leave out the singleton case - the x:xs case covers it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

you get this because your result is a list-of-pairs, where the second-part of the first item in that list is some element and the second-part of the second item in your result list is, whatever you are trying to give back (you use recursion here so it will have the same type) - so you say:

> my result is a list-of-tuples, but part of those tuples is the result-type itself

that is what the error tells you

---

here are some details:

look at your last line

```
skipBigram (x:xs) = [(x, (head xs)), (x, skipBigram xs)]
```

you have a list of tuples on the right side so it's type will be like (based on the first element of the result list):

```
skipBigram :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
```

but in the second-item you have `(x, skipBigram xs)` meaning it will have the type `(a, [(a,a)])` (remember the type of `skipBigram xs` is the above part).

and so - comparing the second parts of the tuples - you have `a ~ [(a,a)]` which produces your error because somehow the type `a` should be the same as `[(a,a)]` which you could expand in all eternity ;)

---

now to the algorithm itself:

It will not work like this - you somehow have to get all combinations and to do this you have to work with the items in the list.

Usually you either do this with list-comprehensions or with the do-notation of the list-monad.

To get going think about this:

```
f [] = [[]]
f (x:xs) =
  let xss = f xs
  in [ x:xs | xs <- xss ] ++ xss
```

test it and play with it in ghci - you will have to combine this with what you got somehow

(ok recursion.ninja ^^ spoiled your fun - I'll let this here anyway if you don't mind)

Comment: @recursion.ninja I am perfectly aware of this (I test my snippets before I post them) ... the idea was to let him experiment with it and solve the problem by himself ;) (if you understand the one I gave you should be able to understand/write all kind of combinatorial stuff ...)

Comment: I understand your pedagogical approach. I wonder if @Jono can see *why* it computes too much by comparing our answers... likely a good exercise!

Answer (score 1):

The infinite type error is complaining about your use of lists. Your function should have the type `[a] -> [a] -> [(a, a)]`, but when GHC tries to infer your function's type, it gets that `a = [a]`, an infinite type. Relevant bindings are just the types of other variables which may be causing the error.

However, even ignoring the type errors, your function will not do what you want at all. Firstly, your function will always return a list of length two, because you have explicitly constructed the list. Also, the result would include `("Colorless", "Colorless")`, because `(x, head xs)` is the same here as `(x, x)`.

Instead, try this solution

```
skipBigram :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
skipBigram [] = []
skipBigram (x:xs) = map (x,) xs ++ skipBigram xs
```

For this function to work, you will need to put the line

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
```

at the beginning of your file.

Comment: `skipBigram (x:xs) = map (x,) xs` doesn't make any recursive calls... so it won't generate the desired result list